# How to append custom style in embed html body

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

```
<embed src="url" id="idembed" width='100%' height='600' /> 
 <iframe src="url" id="idframe"   style="width: 100%;height:600px;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
```

please help me is there any way to find embed content to append custom style in head section.

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: No you can't do that. Think if it is possible then i can embed the `google` site and replace with my own logo instead of google logo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this then

```
<html>
<body>

  <iframe  id="emb" src="url"></iframe>

<script>
 var iframe = document.getElementByID('emb');
 var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument;

 // now iframeDoc variable has the reference to the document of the iframe
// assuming there is a paragraph in Iframe with id= "change"

 var p= iframeDoc.getElementByID('change');
 p.style.backgroundColor="red";

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No i want to add html page url and add custom style dynamically in to the embed html page head section

Comment: if the solution is not clear you can try this url http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/refs/iframe.php

Comment: Thanks for your support